ASP.NET Core Razor page async OnGet handler causing intermittent errors if not set to return a Task
In my async OnGet Razor page handler I'm calling async methods (all awaited) that populate the Razor page model used in the Razor view for rendering content. What I noticed is that until I turned the async void signature into async Task I was getting intermittent errors during Razor view rendering. I understood that Razor page handlers that return void or Task implicitly return a PageResult (an action result that renders the associated Razor page) which in my head meant that a Razor view will not start being rendered until the end of the OnGet method is reached (i.e. until async methods inside the OnGet handler have all completed). But from what I see, it looks like the Razor view rendering is done by an ASP.NET engine method that calls the OnGet handler and waits for it, if it can (async Task), or not, if it can't (async void). Here another post reporting the same exact behavior.
Is it correct then that it is not this implicit or even explicit  return of PageResult that starts the view rendering?

by making that method async and returning a Task, the server won't have to lock the thread to wait for the response.  I believe the Page() method is called implicitly so you don't need a return statement.  Page() creates a PageResult. PageResult is an IActionResult.  See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel.page?view=aspnetcore-8.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-razorpages-pagemodel-page  It'll be wrapped in a Task if you use the "async" keyword in the method declaration.  (when Task is completed page will be rendered)

I agree with you, the asp.net engine without a Task being return will not wait on the OnGet method to complete and concurrency may sometimes play against you (something required by the page rendering logic might not be yet available).

non async onGet will wait and block the thread.  Concurrency might happen with DB requests from different users. (those would happen when DB updates happen though)  There are different strategies to deal with that.  If you have problems with concurrency either in the requests or in DB management you should ask a new question with code to reproduce.

@browsermator this does not seem to be true because I'm getting intermittent errors that suggest that sometimes page rendering occurs before async methods within the async onGet method have completed their execution

You'll want to create a question for that with the code.  And I believe you'll want OnGetAsync.
